# How can we make Dynamic Table Column Name Header title in 2 lines?

Tags: wicket

I am creating dynamic table using AbstractColumn.
I needs to display column title in 2 line. 
Is it possible in wicket?

Ex: My column header is "Add/Edit Team Leads"
I want it in "Add/Edit \n Team Leads"

\n is not working here.

Please help.

Comment: `\n` won't work in a plain HTML too. You need `<br/>` to have a new line in HTML. MultilineLabel automatically converts all `\n`s to `<br/>`s.

Answer (score 1):

Override #getHeader(String) to return a MultiLineLabel:

```
@Override
public Component getHeader(final String componentId)
{
    return new MultiLineLabel(componentId, getDisplayModel());
}
```